# Javafx Splitpane divider positions on resizing the parent pane

Tags: javafx, splitpane

I have a splitpane with three children, but I want to show just the 2 top or the 2 bottom children at a time. So I implement a sliding animation, which slide the splitpane in a parent pane up and down.
The sliding animation works fine, but when I resize the parent pane I have a problem with the divider positions. How can I make sure, that the divider positions are always correct?
The image should makes my idea clear.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to force the divider to always stay in the middle? You can use highlevel binding:

```
splitPane.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty()
            .bind(splitPane.heightProperty().divide(2));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Divider.position : A bound value cannot be set.`.